# Turn HP 8620 pro paper sensor off

Tags: drivers, printer

I bought a HP Officejet 8620 Pro and installed it. Everything works great, until I wanted to print on our companys branded paper. This A4 sheets have an edge cut off in the top left corner. The paper sensor on this printer then detects this paper as the wrong format, displays an error message and stops printing.

After consulting the HP forums on turning off the paper sensor, it turned out that this sensor cannot be turned off with the printer driver settings.

Is there a way to turn off the sensor manually, with a manipulated driver or another cheap trick? If not, is it possible to change the feed direction, so that the cut off edge does not pass the sensor (I was able to print on the back of our branded paper, but this is no option)?

Comment: What operating system are you using (might make a difference in drivers or third-party solutions available)?  I can think of a convoluted workaround, but it wouldn't be practical for regular use.  Does the 8620 include a built-in duplexer?  If so, does it ignore the paper sensor when printing on the reverse side from the duplexer?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit, latest service pack installed. Let me try that with the duplexer, this might work.

Comment: Just curious if the duplexer test worked.  If not, update your question and see if anyone has other ideas.

Comment: After some failed tries we managed to contact a HP technician, he was able to install the printer with a different driver which can reverse the side and everything works fine. We just have to remember which printer driver to select when printing on company paper. Thanks for pointing us in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Sensors in the paper path are there to tell the printer when it has a paper jam, so it is extremely unlikely the printer will let you turn it off. However, you may be able to disable it somehow, by taping a little piece of paper in the right position.

If the sensor is a mechanical switch that drops down, this piece of paper may stop it from dropping. If it's an optical sensor, the piece of paper may reflect the light in the same way as a sheet of paper would. Either way, if this works, the printer will think there is paper present. Not knowing the internal details of your printer, you will need to experiment.

Either way, this may still cause a paper jam as the printer will "see" paper at that switch at all times, so it may think the paper is not moving properly. Again, only experiment will show.

If it works, this will have the side effect that the printer may not be able to tell when it fails to pick paper, so it may start to print without any paper being present, causing a mess of ink in the printer.

For this reason, I DO NOT RECOMMEND THIS!

Comment: Thx for the input, I thought of that as well, but the last thing I want is to clean an ink mess. Therefore I will look for an other solution.